# Call Soap Service from Firebase Cloud function Error

Tags: firebase, soap, google-cloud-functions

I want to call a soap service url from my firebase cloud function

1. I've already enabled billing, and I am able to call other api's from my cloud function.
2. I can call this soap function on postman, and it works.
   [image]

But, Calling it from my cloud function gives me the following error.

**XMLHttpRequest Error:**

```
"Message": "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80\n    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)\n    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1105:14)"
```

**Code**

```
  var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        //replace second argument with the path to your Secret Server webservices
        xmlhttp.open('POST', 'xxxxx/SiloFunctions.asmx');

        //create the SOAP request
        var sr =
            '<soapenv:Envelope ' +
            'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
            'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
            'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
            '<soap:Body>' +
            '<Request xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">' +
            '<Password>xxxx</Password>' +
            '<Latitude>123</Latitude>' +
            '<Longitude>123</Longitude>' +
            '<ClientName>123</ClientName>' +
            '<ClientSurname>123</ClientSurname>' +
            '<MSISDN>123123</MSISDN>' +
            '</Request>' +
            '</soap:Body>' +
            '</soapenv:Envelope>';


        //specify request headers
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');

        //FOR TESTING: display results in an alert box once the response is received
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                res.status(200).send(
                    {
                        "Message": xmlhttp.responseText,
                    })
            }
        };

        //send the SOAP request
        xmlhttp.send(sr);
```

Whyyyyyy?

Comment: On which payment plan are you? The free "Spark" plan allows outbound network requests **only to Google-owned services**. You need to be on the "Flame" or "Blaze" plan. See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: Yup, I am on Blaze

Comment: `xxxxx` is kind of important here.  Can you give a clue to what you're putting in there?

Comment: @DougStevenson that would be  someUrl.com/API/SiloFunctions.asmx

Comment: Is that exactly how it's formatted?

Comment: @DougStevenson Yup, exactly.  someurl.com/999API/SiloFunctions.asmx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the full URL, not a partial URL.  It probably starts with `https://`.  Since you're not using that, the HTTP library you're using is assuming localhost (127.0.0.1), which obviously isn't going to work.

Comment: That was Exactly it. Thanks! (And as a bonus, they are running it on http:// and not https:// So that is also being blocked.